# how to get rid of the jscroll separator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so, i am using something called 'jscroll'(http://jscroll.com) in order to bring about infinite scrolling.

http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request

here is the board that uses jscroll to load contents infinitely.

but as you scroll through, notice there's a separator after 10 lists.

that's because the jscroll is adding the '.jscrolladded' div between the .masonrys

is it possible to get rid of the.jscrolladded, as well as the '.masonry' that wrapps the .items?

here is the script that i use.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.board_content').jscroll({
loadingHtml: '<div class="loading_div"><center><img src="layouts/wb10    /ajax-loader4.gif" alt="Loading" /></center></div>',
padding: 0,
contentSelector: '.board_list',
autoTriggerUntil: 30,
nextSelector:'.next_button',
callback: function() {

 jQuery('.masonry').masonry({
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
    itemSelector: '.item'
});


 jQuery('.list_one').waypoint(function() {
  jQuery('.list_one').addClass('animated fadeIn');
  }, {
     offset: '75%'
});
}
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

May be adding

```
.jscrolladded
{
display:none;
}
```

in your CSS could help/

Comment: bad guess :D Is it possible to get class or ID of the element you want to hide simply hide it with code above ?